# Crystal Report Sum of a Column data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have field GrandTotal in my dataset which I am showing in my report. I want show the total of all data in the footer .

My column data are string .

I tried to make a formula as bellow

```
 SUM(ToNumber({Ds.Grandtotal}))
```

But its saying a field is require.

Comment: And why cannot you just insert sum of your GrandTotal field into report footer? So far Crystal Reports has allowed that.

Comment: we can convert the column to number at query level? have you tried that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must convert the field into number, and then try to get the sum.

Step 1: Create a new formula from field explorer, give a name to formula (relevant name).

Step 2: Convert the field into Number.

Step 3: Then Add Sum of the formula field

Step 4: Place that Formula field into the Report Footer.

Add Formula:

[image]

Choose Field to Convert into Number or Currency:

[image]

Then After Field Conversion, get the Sum of the Formula field by choosing name of the formula from the Report fields.
Formula field has fx as prefix.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try below solution.

1. Create a formula and write formula as

`ToNumber({Ds.Grandtotal})`
now place this formula in details section.

1. Now write on the placed formula and click on summary and insert summary to grand total.

Comment: The output showing ### in both details and footer . i followed your steps . why is that?

Comment: Increse the size of the field.. I will set right automatically