# Grand total with each summation in crystall report

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, subtotal

I have data like this

```
Type     Buy   Sell

Car1    23000  15000
Car2    24000
Car3    25000
```

I used `sum(@buy)` for total buy field and `sum(@sell)` for total sell field.

Can I sum all or grand total that like `sum(@buy) + sum(@sell)` ?

because when I run in `VB6` for preview that report, Grand total not show on, please help me master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this there are 2 approach.

1. Via Formula :- add a formula field and in that add give above condition in formula field editor. put this field in your desired location, but ideally put in report footer or group footer(if any).
2. Use running total or summary total.

Check this links

[Crystal Report Sum of a Column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082880/crystal-report-sum-of-a-column-data)

https://forums.asp.net/t/1971464.aspx?Sum+of+Total+in+Crystal+Report+